# HTTP/2 Server Push a stylesheet with variables and make it work each time I change the variable?

Tags: nginx, https, http-headers, http2, server-push

I´m HTTP/2 Server Pushing my Wordpress style.css this way:

```
## Server push 
add_header link "</wp-content/themes/template/style.css?ver=20170228a>; rel=preload; as=styles";
```

It works like a charm but when I change the **style.css?ver=20170228a** version, I´ll update the variable string so recurring visitors can re-cache the new File easier, ie: style.css**?ver=20170303a**.

Is there any way to implement this in the **add_header link rule**??? Something like (which obv not works but like using variables):

```
add_header link "</wp-content/themes/template/css/$uri?$args>; rel=preload; as=styles";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, i am sending those by php. Might this be a solution to you?
No idea about nginx, sry.